# Should I say "these are what I do" or "this is what I do"?

Tags: word-choice, idiomatic-language, demonstrative-pronouns

Should I say "these are what I do" or "this is what I do"? Specifically, in the context of a self-description, for example: "Cooking, hiking and painting - these are what I do", vs. "... - this is what I do".

Is one of the options better than the other (more grammatical / more common / sounds better)?

Comment: What do you think could be ungrammatical about it? Can you add more details? Compare: "... these are **all** what I do"

Comment: What @Kris said, asking "Is it grammatical?" or "Is it good English?" is off-topic unless a specific concern is identified. ELU doesn't provide a proof-reading service and please visit Help Center and read the guidelines.

Answer (score 2):

> Cooking, hiking and painting - this is what I do

Saying "this is what I do" is idiomatic for describing how you spend your free time or describing your hobbies.  Can be used to describe your job or habits as well.

> Cooking, hiking and painting - these are what I do

This implies that literally the only things you do are cooking, hiking, and painting.